# Normal high lymphocyte count in children

Tags: white-blood-count

Even if children have a weak immune system and are prone to inffections, it is considered physiological for them to have lymphocytosis. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

Such type of relative lymphocytosis may be due to:

1)vaccinations in children

Vaccinations increase the number and the types of antigens available to the developing T-cells for their central tolerance.

Thymus is the centre for central tolerence of the T-cells.The T-cells are so important for the immunity in children because they (memory T-cells)can also trigger the formation of B-cells for humoural immunity.

B-cells,however undergo [central tolerance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tolerance) in the bone marrow.[[REFERENCE]](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.4161/hv.28559)

2)Thymus activity which is at peak during the period from childhood to puberty.[[REFERENCE]](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thymic_involution)